# iOS Safari - Playing media element (from click) with delay - NotAllowedError

Tags: javascript, html, ios, safari, mediaelement

iOS Safari requires a touch event to play/pause media elements. Without, you get the:

> NotAllowedError: The request is not allowed by the user agent or the platform in the current context, possibly because the user denied permission.
>   caught promiseReaction error message.

The question is "How to delay the <MediaElement>.play() call without loosing the touch event context??"

I'm trying to play a media element with a delay after the click, but in the two methods I've come up with (Promise & setTimeout), they both loose the connection to the touch event and I get the NotAllowedError error due to the scope change of the <MediaElement>.play() call. Both work on all ES6 devices/browsers other than iOS Safari, as expected.

Feel free to play with it [here](https://codepen.io/joeweitzel/pen/zgvyYv?editors=0010) on codepen.

```
const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));

const video = document.querySelector('video'),
      button = document.querySelector('button')

const playVideoSyncDelay = async e => {
  document.body.classList.add('blackground')
  await delay(3000)
  video.play()
    .then( e => video.onended = e => document.body.classList.remove('blackground', 'playing') )
    .then( e => document.body.classList.add('playing') )
    .catch( e => console.error('Oops:', e) )
}

const playVideoTimeoutDelay = e => {
  document.body.classList.add('blackground')
  setTimeout(e => {
    video.play()
      .then( e => video.onended = e => document.body.classList.remove('blackground', 'playing') )
      .then( e => document.body.classList.add('playing') )
      .catch( e => console.error('Oops:', e) )
  }, 3000, e)
}

/**
BOTH BELOW RESULT IN DELAYED NotAllowedError: ...not in the current context...
**/
//button.onclick = playVideoTimeoutDelay;
button.onclick = playVideoSyncDelay;
```

Comment: Did you ever come up with a fix for this?

Comment: I don’t even remember asking this question, but I think this could be done in this order: 1) call <media>.load)

Comment: Oops hit submit too soon. Inside your onclick =e=> { <MediaEl>.load(); setTimeout(()=> <MediaEl>.play(), 1000); }

Comment: Havt tested but .load() should give the user access to control the Media Element, and then they can call .play() with a delay. I don’t think .load with play the media but in case it does, pause it after load() and before setTimeout().

Answer (score 2):

If the user calls .load() before the delayed .play(), they can delayed play on mobile browsers.

Here is a codepen:
https://codepen.io/joeweitzel/pen/RwJVBNL
`$media.load(); $setTimeout(()=>$media.play, 2000)`